# Compute $\int_{\gamma} \frac{z}{z^3-1} dz$ where $\gamma$ is circle centered at origin of radius 2

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Compute $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{z}{z^3-1} dz$$ where $\gamma(t)=2e^{it}$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

The first part of the problem had me compute the same integral over the path $\gamma(t)=\frac{1}{2} e^{it}$. I used Cauchy's Integral Formula with $z_0 =1$ and $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}$, which is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus \{-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i\}$. However, given that $\gamma$, we could easily find an open convex $U$ such that $\gamma\in U$ and $f(z)$ is analytic on $U$. Thus, I obtained the result $0$.

For this part, we cannot find an open convex $U$ such that $\gamma\in U$ and $f(z)$ is analytic on all of $U$, since the singularities are contained in the path circle. I believe I need to separate the region into multiple parts, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using partial fractions?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't know about the residue theorem yet. Do you confirm this?

Comment: @GitGud Correct, I do not know this yet. Most of the problems in this section seem to be solved using Cauchy's Integral Formula and Cauchy's Integral Theorem for convex sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_\gamma \dfrac{z}{z^3-1}dz=\int_\gamma \dfrac{z}{(z-1)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}dz,$$

with $z_1=-\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}i$ and $z_2=-\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}i$. Now:

$$\int_\gamma \dfrac{z}{(z-1)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}dz= \int_{\gamma_1} \dfrac{z/\{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\}}{(z-1)}dz + \int_{\gamma_2} \dfrac{z/\{(z-1)(z-z_1)\}}{(z-z_2)}dz +\int_{\gamma_3} \dfrac{z/\{(z-1)(z-z_2)\}}{(z-z_1)}dz, $$

with $\gamma_1$ a circle around the pole $z=1$, $\gamma_2$ around $z_2$ and $\gamma_3$ around $z_1$. Using Cauchy's Integral Formula:

$$\int_{\gamma_1} \dfrac{z/\{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\}}{(z-1)}dz = 2\pi i \dfrac{1}{(1-z_1)(1-z_2)},$$
$$\int_{\gamma_2} \dfrac{z/\{(z-1)(z-z_1)\}}{(z-z_2)}dz = 2\pi i \dfrac{z_2}{(z_2-1)(z_2-z_1)},$$
$$\int_{\gamma_3} \dfrac{z/\{(z-1)(z-z_2)\}}{(z-z_1)}dz= 2\pi i \dfrac{z_1}{(z_1-1)(z_1-z_2)}. $$

I leave the calculations to you.